# rpath in LDFLAGS for CMAKE

Tags: cmake, rpath, ldflags

I am currently porting my automake into CMAKE. I am trying to find what's equivalent of:

```
myprogram_LDFLAGS = \
   -lcurl \
   -ldl \
   -lresolv \
    -Wl,-rpath,'/approot/services/lib'
```

**What is the corresponding command in cmake to set my rpath?**

```
set(CMAKE_INSTALL_RPATH "/approot/services/lib")
```

The above command seems to be related to the install time. Whereas, LDFLAGS are linker related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
set_target_properties(${TARGET} PROPERTIES LINK_FLAGS "-Wl,-rpath,'/approot/services/lib'")
```

Comment: The full CMake equivalent would probably also include: `target_link_libraries(${TARGET} PUBLIC curl dl resolv)`